# RSVP for event using ios sdk 3.0

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am having trouble rsvp-ing to facebook events retrieved using the new sdk and fql. The documentation indicates that I can send some http-post to me/events, but it does not say anything more specific than that, and that seems to fall outside of the new sdk.

So, is there a way to set the RSVP status for an event using the new facebook sdk 3.0 for ios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in case anyone else stumbles across this question.

All you have to do is create a FBRequest object using:

```
[FBRequest requestForPostWithGraphPath:@"<EVENT ID HERE>/attending" graphObject:nil];
```

and start it. It will set the currently logged in user as attending the event (so long as you have the correct permissions)